# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int-http:outbound-gateway'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int-http:outbound-gateway'

> common-context.xml has the following under beans
>
> 1. xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
> 2. http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
>            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <int:splitter input-channel="cvsSplitter" output-channel="statusChunkRequests" ref="cvsPagingSplitter"/>
    <int:channel id="cvsResponseEventCreator"><int:queue/></int:channel>
    <int:channel id="eventNotificationServiceCall"></int:channel>
    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="cvsResponse"/>
    <int:chain input-channel="eventNotificationServiceCall" output-channel="eventPostChannel">
        <int:transformer>
            <bean class="com.abc.xyz.InventoryEventTransformer"/>
        </int:transformer>
    </int:chain>
    <int:chain input-channel="cvsResponseEventCreator" output-channel="eventPostChannel">
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="100" fixed-rate="1000"/>
        <int:header-enricher>
           <int:correlation-id value="correlateAll" />
        </int:header-enricher>
        <int:aggregator>
            <bean class="com.abc.xyz.InventoryEventTransformer"/>
        </int:aggregator>
    </int:chain>
    <int:chain input-channel="eventPostChannel" output-channel="nullChannel">
        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="Content-Type" expression="'application/json'"/>
        </int:header-enricher>
        <int-http:outbound-gateway http-method="POST"
                                   expected-response-type="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode"
                                   charset="UTF-8"
                                   request-factory="clientHttpRequestFactory"
                                   url="${inv.event.rest.base.url}" reply-timeout="${inv.event.timeout}">
            <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
                <ref bean="retrier" />
            </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
        </int-http:outbound-gateway>
    </int:chain>
```

The error occurs during run time "mvn spring-boot:run" only when the application is upgraded from spring-boot 1.3 to 1.4. The app works fine with spring-boot 1.3

```
     [WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:507)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [integration/common-context.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [application-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 47 in XML document from class path resource [integration/common-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 47; columnNumber: 106; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int-http:outbound-gateway'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:259)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.cdk.dmg.remarketing.RemarketingInventoryLoaderApplication.main(RemarketingInventoryLoaderApplication.java:32)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 47 in XML document from class path resource [integration/common-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 47; columnNumber: 106; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int-http:outbound-gateway'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:243)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 47; columnNumber: 106; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int-http:outbound-gateway'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:458)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3237)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1917)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:746)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:379)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 36 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.944 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-19T15:08:53+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 62M/779M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project remarketing-inventory-loader: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [integration/common-context.xml]
[ERROR] Offending resource: class path resource [application-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 47 in XML document from class path resource [integration/common-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 47; columnNumber: 106; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int-http:outbound-gateway'.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot(1.4.X) onwards below modules has been removed
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes

- spring-integration-file

  spring-integration-http

  spring-integration-ip

  spring-integration-stream

This problem can be resolved by adding the missing dependencies in pom.xml

Comment: You should make your questions clearer in future. If you had added `The app works fine with spring-boot 1.3` in the original question, it would have saved you (and me) a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a runtime problem, you are missing the the `spring-integration-http` jar from your classpath.

If it's just an error in the IDE (and works at runtime), it means your IDE is not "spring-aware"; spring resolves the correct schema from the class path in the jar. for historical reasons, the non-versioned schema on the internet is the 1.0 version (see the note in the schema for the reason why).

Spring-Aware IDEs include eclipse (with the spring ide plugins), [Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools/sts) which is eclipse + plugins, and IntelliJ IDEA.

With the eclipse plugins, you add Spring Nature to your project and it will find the schema.

If you are using eclipse and don't want to use the plugins, ignore the errors or manually configure the XML Catalog to point to the versioned schema.

Comment: Gary - The error occurs during run time "mvn spring-boot:run" only when the application is upgraded from spring-boot 1.3 to 1.4. The app works fine with spring-boot 1.3

Comment: The integration starter now only adds the `spring-integration-core` jar to the class path - people complained about class path bloat (getting jars they don't need). You now have to add `spring-integration-http` yourself.